# How to create a directory in "/"

Tags: filesystem

I'm trying to build my own linux distro using "linux from scratch" project.
In order to do so I need to access different features, On my development process I went through many troubles in Ubuntu One among them was I cannot able to create a directory in "/" .
How to do that ?

Comment: open terminal and go to `/` by `cd /` then `sudo mkdir <directory name>` or open nautilus with sudo `sudo nautilus`

Comment: @achu  why not make it an answer ;)

Comment: It will not work @Achu

Comment: @Rinzwind Ok i will make it :)

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and go to `/` by `cd /` then `sudo mkdir <directory name>`

or

Open nautilus with sudo `sudo nautilus`

Comment: ...and be VERY careful when running Nautilus using sudo.  You could accidentally delete or change important files or wipe your entire / directory!!  So if you do use sudo Nautilus to create a directory in /, close Nautilus immediately to avoid problems.

Comment: Yeah, good point.